# How do I use ViewBag string in partial view javascript

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am returning this from a partial view:

```
<script>
    document.getElementById("login").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("displayname").innerHTML = @ViewBag.DisplayName  
</script>
```

The second script line, however, does not work.

How to write this correctly?

Greg

Comment: what does "does not work" mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Html.Raw("document.getElementById(\"displayname\").innerHTML = " + @ViewBag.DisplayName)
```